# Is there a better way to write this "if" boolean evaluation?

Tags: python, if-statement

I have this small snippet of python code that I wrote. It works, but I think there should be a more streamlined method to achieve the same results. I'm just not seeing it. Any ideas?

```
if tx_avt >= 100: tx = 1 
elif tx_avt < 100 and tx_avt >= 50: tx = 2 
elif tx_avt < 50 and tx_avt >= 25: tx = 3
elif tx_avt < 25 and tx_avt >= 12.5: tx = 4 
else: tx = 5
```

Comment: This would be more readable if you put the assignments on their own line properly indented.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can change it to:

```
if tx_avt >= 100: tx = 1 
elif tx_avt >= 50: tx = 2 
elif tx_avt >= 25: tx = 3
elif tx_avt >= 12.5: tx = 4 
else: tx = 5
```

**Explanation:**

- If `if tx_avt >= 100` is not true, then you can deduce that `tx_avt < 100` **must** be true.
- This eliminates the need to do the "`tx_avt < 100`" part in the check "`elif tx_avt < 100 and tx_avt >= 50:`".

The same logic cascades down & applies to the rest of the `elif` cases.

---

Related reading: [Why Python Doesn't Have a Switch Statement, and its Alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374239/why-doesnt-python-have-a-switch-statement).

Comment: most complete answer so far!

Comment: Ah of course! It is now obvious to me! for some reason I had it in my head I must evaluate between the number with the AND statement. Thanks for the clarification. Ideally, I would have used a switch/case statement if I was using c++. Much cleaner. So goes it. I will check out the link.

Answer (score 10):

you dont need the upper bounds on the elifs since these are resolved by the clause above them  ...

```
elif tx_avt >= 50 : #do something
elif tx_avt >= 25 : #somthing else
```

on a side note in python you can do

```
if 3 < ab < 10 : #check if ab is between 3 and 10
```

Comment: The interval-check is interresting! Do you know where it can be found in the language reference? Would love to see how the evaluation works for other types than integers

Comment: there is a little bit in the first paragraph here http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in

Comment: Ah that is an interesting tidbit I did not know about Pyhton. thanks!

Answer (score 8):

If your if-elif-else chain gets really long you can use this method:

```
for amt, tx in [(100, 1), (50, 2), (25, 3), (12.5, 4)]:
    if tx_avt >= amt:
        break
else:
    tx = 5
```

**note:** The `else` clause of a `for` loop is executed when `break` has not been encountered.  In this case it is used to provide the default case.

Comment: your note is slightly wrong ... the else executes if you are not in an if or elif block when you exit the loop ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley:  Incorrect.  See Python docs [4.4. `break` and `continue` Statements, and `else` Clauses on Loops](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops): "Loop statements may have an `else` clause; it is executed when the loop terminates through exhaustion of the list (with `for`) or when the condition becomes false (with `while`), but not when the loop is terminated by a `break` statement."

Comment: oh cool thanks :) ... I thought those were executed differently but good to know

Answer (score 3):

To give another idea, this can be done in a one liner using the binary search function in the bisect module.

```
In [106]: def index(a,x):
   .....:         return len(a) - bisect.bisect_right(a, x) + 1
   .....:

In [107]: a=[12.5,25,50,100]

In [108]: index(a,15)
Out[108]: 4

In [109]: index(a,25)
Out[109]: 3

In [110]: index(a,35)
Out[110]: 3

In [111]: index(a,50)
Out[111]: 2

In [112]: index(a,100)
Out[112]: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another idea based on the fact that [12.5, 25, 50, 100] is a series:

```
MAX_BOUNDARY = 5
for tx, boundary in [(n, 25 * 2**(-n+3)) for n in range(1, MAX_BOUNDARY)]:
    if tx_avt >= boundary:
        break
else:
    tx = MAX_BOUNDARY
```

(This is slightly modified @StevenRumbalski version)

This could be combined with @WaiYipTung idea about `bisect` for O(log(n)) search if distribution of tx_avt is uniform (w.r.t. series function) and your list grows VERY large.

Otherwise you should stick to simpler and easier to understand solutions like @JoranBeasley and @SampsonChen suggested.